# Unsubscribes: Where is the status stored?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

I'm not sure I understand how the unsubscribe status is stored.

I'm sending to a number of custom data extensions. If I include the opt out link in my email footer and a user clicks it, how is it stored in ET that this user has unsubbed from this list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you send to a Data Extension without associating a Publication List, then the subscriber is opted out in All Subscribers ([Subscribers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/)).

If you associate a Publication List with your send, then they'll be unsubscribed at the List Subscriber level ([ListSubscribers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_listsubscribers/)).

There are some differences between the different SFMC Account types, but generally speaking, this is how it's handled.